# Meteor+mochaでテストが実行されない

Tags: テスト, meteor

Meteorと[meteor-mocha-web](https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-mocha-web)でテストを動かそうとしていますが、テストをmochaに見つけてもらえません。

```sh
$ meteor add mike:mocha@0.4.4 # 別の問題を回避するため現時点での最新版をインストール
$ mkdir -p tests/server/unit
```

[サンプルのテスト](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity-examples/blob/master/leaderboard-mocha/tests/mocha/server/serverTest.js)をコピペして、確実に落ちるように修正:

`tests/server/unit/test.js`

```js
if (!(typeof MochaWeb === 'undefined')){
  MochaWeb.testOnly(function(){
    describe("Server initialization", function(){
      it("should insert players into the database after server start", function(){
        chai.assert(0 > 0);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

meteorを実行

```sh
$ meteor
```

アプリの画面をブラウザで開くと右上に青い丸が出て、詳細を見ると "0 tests passed in 0 ms" と出ています。

何か手順を間違えているでしょうか。

Comment: testingのタグを追加しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[meteor-mocha-webは`tests/mocha/`の下にあるファイルしかロードしない](https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-mocha-web/blob/71201992a494a97e5a72d2afc4b805ea979ae982/server.js#L9)ので、テストコードの置き場所を変える必要があります。

```
$ mkdir -p tests/mocha/server/unit
```